# Adding an another line

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small #3} & \textit{\small #4} 
      %\textit{\small #6} & \textit{\small #7} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{http://google.com/}{\Large XYZ}} & Email : 
\href{mailto:xyz@gmail.com}{xyz@gmail.com}\\  
  \href{http://google.com/}{http://www.xyz.com} & 
\href{mailto:xyz@gmail.com}{xyz@gmail.com} \\
  & Mobile : +0000000000
\end{tabular*}

%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Good University}{xyz, Unknown}
      {Doctor of Philosophy in Swimming}{Sep. 2021 -- April. 2028}   
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd   
\end{document}
```

I wants to add an another line under Doctor of Philosophy. Which custom command should be modified ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:latex3]? You're loading outdated packages such as `latexsym`

Comment: Hmmh, did you yourself invent all the macros? If so, why do you have a problem modifying them? If not, why don't you disclose the source?

Comment: Not a solution, just a cheat with tabular: `{\begin{tabular}{l}Doctor of Philosophy in Swimming\\Another Line\end{tabular}}{Sep. 2021 -- April. 2028}` :P

Comment: Apparently this should be a resume or cv: Try something like `moderncv` etc.

Comment: @marmot: I didn't write it by myself. The source is https://github.com/sb2nov/resume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
\usepackage{makecell}
```

to your preamble and update `\resumeSubheading` to resemble

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small #3} & \textit{\small #4}
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

(the addition of a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular`), you can use

```
%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Good University}{xyz, Unknown}
      {\makecell[tl]{Doctor of Philosophy in Swimming \\ and Paddling}}
      {Sep.~2021 -- April.~2028}   
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

[image]