# Resume/CV template with custom subheading, subheading is too long and spills over page width

Tags: formatting

The custom subheading set by the CV is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\CVSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \small#3 & \small #4 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```

The first item in the tabular environment is too long and spills over the right side of the page. The code of my table is as follows:

```
\CVSubheading
      {{Very long text that spills over}}{2023}
      {University name}{}
```

If anyone has a solution it would be much appreciated, I'm not very proficient in latex and always struggle with small formatting errors like this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332903, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286967 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407983 help?

Comment: Yes!!! perfect, the third link gave the 'makecell' package where I could change the cell to [tl], amazing thank you!!!

Comment: yup, thats the one, thanks